# Tracking offline purchases with Enhanced Ecommerce and Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

We've deployed Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce to better track our sales. Everything's working great except that some of our transactions are paid offline. We were already using the "standard" ecommerce analytics and this had been solved by reporting these transactions with the Measurement Protocol.

Right now we're unable to use MP in conjunction with Enhanced Ecommerce. Our reports seem to be accepted by the collection engine but they're not being linked to the Shopping Behaviour / Checkout Behaviour Reports (which is crucial for us).

Since the Enhanced Ecommerce is working for online payments, we're narrowing this down to our Measurement Protocol usage.
Here's an example of one such call:

```
'v' => 1,
'tid' => 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3',
'cid' => 'YYYYYYYYYY',
't' => 'pageview',
'ti' => 219950,
'ta' => 'our property name',
'tr' => 14.99,
'pa' => 'purchase',
'ni' => '0',
'pr1id' => '53731',
'pr1nm' => 'Product description',
'pr1pr' => '14.99',
'pr1qt' => '1',
'pr1ps' => 1,
```

We've tried sending the Hit Type ('t' parameter) as Event, instead of Pageview, with no success.
We're recording the Client ID ('cid' parameter) on the checkout. We've tried sending it with and without the timestamp (the numeric part that procedes the . separator).
We've trying sending this as a Non-Interactive hit ('ni' parameter).

Comment: have you tried to capture a http request sent by the GA script inyour online purchase scenario. you should be able to see what you're missing in the above request.

Comment: We eventually got this to work by tracking these as events of eCommerce type:
't' => 'event',
'ec' => 'eCommerce',
'ea' => 'Purchase'.